# How can I put new line (\n) in toString?

Tags: java

How can I add *\n* in toString?

```
public String toString() {
    return (friendName+houseNumber+road);
}
```

Comment: Is the missing quote the problem? Or the 2 missing pluses?

Comment: For people, **do not edit the original code in order to solve it**, instead post an answer.

Comment: It would be good to edit your question and add your current and desired output in order to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use StringBuilder and also may your code platform agnostic by querying the line separator

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(friendName).append(System.getProperty("line.separator")); 
    sb.append(houseNumber).append(System.getProperty("line.separator")); 
    sb.append(road)); 
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: So, mark this question as answered. And this anwser as the right one

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
return (friendName+"\n"+houseNumber+"\n"+road);
```

Comment: i done that it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

you haven't concatenated properly, it has to be like this:

```
return (friendName + "\n" + houseNumber + "\n" + road);
```

Comment: The quotes are still off

Comment: I guess this was just a hard to type expression :P Sorry I'd normally have edited but am on a phone

Comment: na i done that it doesn't work

Comment: @user2109126 Then you are doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Addict is correct so:

```
return (friendName+"\n"+houseNumber+"\n"+road);
```

In advance you can try to write the following:

```
return (friendName+"\r\n"+houseNumber+"\r\n"+road);
```

Because it is OS dependent:
Windows: \r\n, Unix: \n, Mac: \r

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
return (friendName+"\n+houseNumber"\n"+road);
```

To this:

```
return (friendName+"\n"+houseNumber+"\n"+road);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
    @Override
    public String toString(){

        return ""+friendName + "\n\n" + houseNumber + "\n\n" + road+"";
    }
```

Comment: Try mine too and tell me if it works please. I'm not at my PC, so I couldn't test it.